# How can I fix the Image horizontal reel scroll slideshow images being stacked vertically?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

The images (logos) are for some reason showing up stacked vertically using this plugin: Image horizontal reel scroll slideshow
https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/image-horizontal-reel-scroll-slideshow

You can see the behavior near the bottom of this page where the sponsors are located: http://tinyurl.com/phu86z9

I've tried re-installing the plugin and changing the type setting. Nothing has fixed this problem.

This is the shortcode I'm using to insert into the page:

```
[ihrss-gallery type="WIDGET" w="940" h="170" speed="3" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" gap="5" random="NO"]
```

There's actually 4 or 5 logos (even though you'll see the same one repeated twice at first glance), the div cuts them off with overflow: hidden, so they're hidden right now.

If you look for this div:

```
<div style="position:relative;width:940px;height: 170px;overflow:hidden">
```

and increase the height to 500px in chrome developer tools, you'll see what I mean.

How can I fix this so that the images line up horizontally as they're supposed to? I would also accept an answer that points me to another plugin that provides the same functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems plugin needed some modifications. Codes are below.

**image-horizontal-reel-scroll-slideshow.js**

```
/**
 *     Image horizontal reel scroll slideshow
 *     Copyright (C) 2011 - 2014 www.gopiplus.com
 * 
 *     This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
 *     it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 *     the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
 *     (at your option) any later version.
 * 
 *     This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 *     but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 *     MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 *     GNU General Public License for more details.
 * 
 *     You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 *     along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 */

var copyspeed=IHRSS_SPEED
IHRSS_SLIDESRARRAY='<nobr><ul style="list-style:none">'+IHRSS_SLIDESRARRAY.join(IHRSS_IMGGAP)+'</ul></nobr>'
var iedom=document.all||document.getElementById
if (iedom)
document.write('<span id="temp" style="visibility:hidden;position:absolute;top:-100px;left:-9000px">'+IHRSS_SLIDESRARRAY+'</span>')
var actualwidth=''
var cross_slide, ns_slide

function fillup(){
if (iedom){
cross_slide=document.getElementById? document.getElementById("test2") : document.all.test2
cross_slide2=document.getElementById? document.getElementById("test3") : document.all.test3
cross_slide.innerHTML=cross_slide2.innerHTML=IHRSS_SLIDESRARRAY
actualwidth=document.all? cross_slide.offsetWidth : document.getElementById("temp").offsetWidth
cross_slide2.style.left=actualwidth+IHRSS_PIXELGAP+"px"
}
else if (document.layers){
ns_slide=document.ns_slidemenu.document.ns_slidemenu2
ns_slide2=document.ns_slidemenu.document.ns_slidemenu3
ns_slide.document.write(IHRSS_SLIDESRARRAY)
ns_slide.document.close()
actualwidth=ns_slide.document.width
ns_slide2.left=actualwidth+IHRSS_PIXELGAP
ns_slide2.document.write(IHRSS_SLIDESRARRAY)
ns_slide2.document.close()
}
lefttime=setInterval("slideleft()",30)
}
window.onload=fillup

function slideleft(){
if (iedom){
if (parseInt(cross_slide.style.left)>(actualwidth*(-1)+8))
cross_slide.style.left=parseInt(cross_slide.style.left)-copyspeed+"px"
else
cross_slide.style.left=parseInt(cross_slide2.style.left)+actualwidth+IHRSS_PIXELGAP+"px"

if (parseInt(cross_slide2.style.left)>(actualwidth*(-1)+8))
cross_slide2.style.left=parseInt(cross_slide2.style.left)-copyspeed+"px"
else
cross_slide2.style.left=parseInt(cross_slide.style.left)+actualwidth+IHRSS_PIXELGAP+"px"

}
else if (document.layers){
if (ns_slide.left>(actualwidth*(-1)+8))
ns_slide.left-=copyspeed
else
ns_slide.left=ns_slide2.left+actualwidth+IHRSS_PIXELGAP

if (ns_slide2.left>(actualwidth*(-1)+8))
ns_slide2.left-=copyspeed
else
ns_slide2.left=ns_slide.left+actualwidth+IHRSS_PIXELGAP
}
}

if (iedom||document.layers){
with (document){
document.write('<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><td>')
if (iedom){
write('<div style="position:relative;width:'+IHRSS_WIDTH+';height:'+IHRSS_HEIGHT+';overflow:hidden">')
write('<div style="position:absolute;width:'+IHRSS_WIDTH+';height:'+IHRSS_HEIGHT+';background-color:'+IHRSS_BGCOLOR+'" onMouseover="copyspeed=0" onMouseout="copyspeed=IHRSS_SPEED">')
write('<div id="test2" style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px"></div>')
write('<div id="test3" style="position:absolute;left:-1000px;top:0px"></div>')
write('</div></div>')
}
else if (document.layers){
write('<ilayer width='+IHRSS_WIDTH+' height='+IHRSS_HEIGHT+' name="ns_slidemenu" bgColor='+IHRSS_BGCOLOR+'>')
write('<layer name="ns_slidemenu2" left=0 top=0 onMouseover="copyspeed=0" onMouseout="copyspeed=IHRSS_SPEED"></layer>')
write('<layer name="ns_slidemenu3" left=0 top=0 onMouseover="copyspeed=0" onMouseout="copyspeed=IHRSS_SPEED"></layer>')
write('</ilayer>')
}
document.write('</td></table>')
}
}
```

i added `ul` tag inside `nobr` tag at line 20

**image-horizontal-reel-scroll-slideshow.php**

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Image horizontal reel scroll slideshow
Plugin URI: http://www.gopiplus.com/work/2011/05/08/wordpress-plugin-image-horizontal-reel-scroll-slideshow/
Description: Image horizontal reel scroll slideshow lets showcase images in a horizontal move style. This slideshow will pause on mouse over. The speed of the plugin gallery is customizable.
Author: Gopi Ramasamy
Version: 11.6
Author URI: http://www.gopiplus.com/work/2011/05/08/wordpress-plugin-image-horizontal-reel-scroll-slideshow/
Donate link: http://www.gopiplus.com/work/2011/05/08/wordpress-plugin-image-horizontal-reel-scroll-slideshow/
Tags: Horizontal, Image, Reel, Scroll, Slideshow, Gallery
License: GPLv2 or later
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
*/

global $wpdb, $wp_version;
define("WP_Ihrss_TABLE", $wpdb->prefix . "Ihrss_plugin");
define("WP_Ihrss_UNIQUE_NAME", "Ihrss");
define('WP_Ihrss_FAV', 'http://www.gopiplus.com/work/2011/05/08/wordpress-plugin-image-horizontal-reel-scroll-slideshow/');

if ( ! defined( 'WP_IHRSS_BASENAME' ) )
    define( 'WP_IHRSS_BASENAME', plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) );

if ( ! defined( 'WP_IHRSS_PLUGIN_NAME' ) )
    define( 'WP_IHRSS_PLUGIN_NAME', trim( dirname( WP_IHRSS_BASENAME ), '/' ) );

if ( ! defined( 'WP_IHRSS_PLUGIN_URL' ) )
    define( 'WP_IHRSS_PLUGIN_URL', WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/' . WP_IHRSS_PLUGIN_NAME );

if ( ! defined( 'WP_IHRSS_ADMIN_URL' ) )
    define( 'WP_IHRSS_ADMIN_URL', get_option('siteurl') . '/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=image-horizontal-reel-scroll-slideshow' );

function Ihrss() 
{
    global $wpdb;
    $Ihrss_package = "";
    $Ihrss_title = get_option('Ihrss_title');
    $Ihrss_sliderwidth = get_option('Ihrss_sliderwidth');
    $Ihrss_sliderheight = get_option('Ihrss_sliderheight');
    $Ihrss_slidespeed = get_option('Ihrss_slidespeed');
    $Ihrss_slidebgcolor = get_option('Ihrss_slidebgcolor');
    $Ihrss_slideshowgap = get_option('Ihrss_slideshowgap');
    $Ihrss_random = get_option('Ihrss_random');
    $Ihrss_type = get_option('Ihrss_type');

    if(!is_numeric($Ihrss_sliderwidth)) { $Ihrss_sliderwidth = 500; }
    if(!is_numeric($Ihrss_sliderheight)) { $Ihrss_sliderheight = 170; }
    if(!is_numeric($Ihrss_slidespeed)) { $Ihrss_slidespeed = 1; }
    if(!is_numeric($Ihrss_slideshowgap)) { $Ihrss_slideshowgap = 5; }

    $Ihrss_slideshowgaphtml = "padding-right:".$Ihrss_slideshowgap."px;";

    $sSql = "select Ihrss_path,Ihrss_link,Ihrss_target,Ihrss_title from ".WP_Ihrss_TABLE." where 1=1";
    if($Ihrss_type <> ""){ $sSql = $sSql . " and Ihrss_type='".$Ihrss_type."'"; }
    if($Ihrss_random == "YES"){ $sSql = $sSql . " ORDER BY RAND()"; }else{ $sSql = $sSql . " ORDER BY Ihrss_order"; }

    $data = $wpdb->get_results($sSql);

    $cnt = 0;
    if ( ! empty($data) ) 
    {
        foreach ( $data as $data ) 
        {
            $Ihrss_path = trim($data->Ihrss_path);
            $Ihrss_link = trim($data->Ihrss_link);
            $Ihrss_target = trim($data->Ihrss_target);
            $Ihrss_title = trim($data->Ihrss_title);
            $Ihrss_package = $Ihrss_package ."IHRSS_SLIDESRARRAY[$cnt]='<li style=\"display:inline-block;\"><a style=\"$Ihrss_slideshowgaphtml\" title=\"$Ihrss_title\"  target=\"$Ihrss_target\" href=\"$Ihrss_link\"><img alt=\"$Ihrss_title\" src=\"$Ihrss_path\" /></a></li>';  ";
            $cnt++;
        }
        ?>
        <script language="JavaScript1.2">
            var IHRSS_WIDTH = "<?php echo $Ihrss_sliderwidth."px"; ?>";
            var IHRSS_HEIGHT = "<?php echo $Ihrss_sliderheight."px"; ?>";
            var IHRSS_SPEED = <?php echo $Ihrss_slidespeed; ?>;
            IHRSS_BGCOLOR = "<?php echo $Ihrss_slidebgcolor; ?>";
            var IHRSS_SLIDESRARRAY=new Array();
            var IHRSS_FINALSLIDE ='';
            <?php echo $Ihrss_package; ?>
            var IHRSS_IMGGAP = " ";
            var IHRSS_PIXELGAP = 1;
            </script>
            <script language="JavaScript1.2" src="<?php echo WP_IHRSS_PLUGIN_URL; ?>/image-horizontal-reel-scroll-slideshow.js"></script>
        <?php
    }   
    else
    {
        _e('No images available in this Gallery Type. Please check admin setting.', 'ihrss');;
    }
}

function Ihrss_install() 
{
    global $wpdb;

    if($wpdb->get_var("show tables like '". WP_Ihrss_TABLE . "'") != WP_Ihrss_TABLE) 
    {
        $sSql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ". WP_Ihrss_TABLE . " (";
        $sSql = $sSql . "Ihrss_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,";
        $sSql = $sSql . "Ihrss_path TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL ,";
        $sSql = $sSql . "Ihrss_link TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL ,";
        $sSql = $sSql . "Ihrss_target VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,";
        $sSql = $sSql . "Ihrss_title VARCHAR( 500 ) NOT NULL ,";
        $sSql = $sSql . "Ihrss_order INT NOT NULL ,";
        $sSql = $sSql . "Ihrss_status VARCHAR( 10 ) NOT NULL ,";
        $sSql = $sSql . "Ihrss_type VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL ,";
        $sSql = $sSql . "Ihrss_extra1 VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL ,";
        $sSql = $sSql . "Ihrss_extra2 VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL ,";
        $sSql = $sSql . "Ihrss_date datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ,";
        $sSql = $sSql . "PRIMARY KEY ( Ihrss_id )";
        $sSql = $sSql . ") ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;";
        $wpdb->query($sSql);

        $IsSql = "INSERT INTO `". WP_Ihrss_TABLE . "` (`Ihrss_path`, `Ihrss_link`, `Ihrss_target` , `Ihrss_title` , `Ihrss_order` , `Ihrss_status` , `Ihrss_type` , `Ihrss_date`)"; 

        $sSql = $IsSql . " VALUES ('".get_option('siteurl')."/wp-content/plugins/image-horizontal-reel-scroll-slideshow/images/Sing_1.jpg', '#', '_blank', 'Image 1', '1', 'YES', 'GROUP1', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');";
        $wpdb->query($sSql);

        $sSql = $IsSql . " VALUES ('".get_option('siteurl')."/wp-content/plugins/image-horizontal-reel-scroll-slideshow/images/Sing_2.jpg' ,'#', '_blank', 'Image 2', '2', 'YES', 'GROUP1', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');";
        $wpdb->query($sSql);

        $sSql = $IsSql . " VALUES ('".get_option('siteurl')."/wp-content/plugins/image-horizontal-reel-scroll-slideshow/images/Sing_3.jpg', '#', '_blank', 'Image 3', '1', 'YES', 'Widget', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');";
        $wpdb->query($sSql);

        $sSql = $IsSql . " VALUES ('".get_option('siteurl')."/wp-content/plugins/image-horizontal-reel-scroll-slideshow/images/Sing_4.jpg', '#', '_blank', 'Image 4', '2', 'YES', 'Widget', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');";
        $wpdb->query($sSql);
    }
    add_option('Ihrss_title', "Horizontal Slideshow");
    add_option('Ihrss_sliderwidth', "400");
    add_option('Ihrss_sliderheight', "75");
    add_option('Ihrss_slidespeed', "1");
    add_option('Ihrss_slidebgcolor', "#ffffff");
    add_option('Ihrss_slideshowgap', "10");
    add_option('Ihrss_random', "YES");
    add_option('Ihrss_type', "Widget");
}

function Ihrss_control() 
{
    echo '<p><b>';
     _e('Image horizontal reel scroll slideshow', 'ihrss');
    echo '.</b> ';
    _e('Check official website for more information', 'ihrss');
    ?> <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo WP_Ihrss_FAV; ?>"><?php _e('click here', 'ihrss'); ?></a></p><?php
}

function Ihrss_widget($args) 
{
    extract($args);
    echo $before_widget . $before_title;
    echo get_option('Ihrss_Title');
    echo $after_title;
    Ihrss();
    echo $after_widget;
}

function Ihrss_admin_options() 
{
    global $wpdb;
    $current_page = isset($_GET['ac']) ? $_GET['ac'] : '';
    switch($current_page)
    {
        case 'edit':
            include('pages/image-management-edit.php');
            break;
        case 'add':
            include('pages/image-management-add.php');
            break;
        case 'set':
            include('pages/image-setting.php');
            break;
        default:
            include('pages/image-management-show.php');
            break;
    }
}

add_shortcode( 'ihrss-gallery', 'Ihrss_shortcode' );

function Ihrss_shortcode( $atts ) 
{
    global $wpdb;

    $Ihrss = "";
    $Ihrss_package = "";

    // New code
    //[ihrss-gallery type="Widget" w="600" h="170" speed="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" gap="10" random="YES"]
    if ( ! is_array( $atts ) ) { return ''; }
    $Ihrss_type = $atts['type'];
    $Ihrss_sliderwidth = $atts['w'];
    $Ihrss_sliderheight = $atts['h'];
    $Ihrss_slidespeed = $atts['speed'];
    $Ihrss_slidebgcolor = $atts['bgcolor'];
    $Ihrss_slideshowgap = $atts['gap'];
    $Ihrss_random = $atts['random'];

    if(!is_numeric($Ihrss_sliderwidth)) { $Ihrss_sliderwidth = 250 ;}
    if(!is_numeric($Ihrss_sliderheight)) { $Ihrss_sliderheight = 200; }
    if(!is_numeric($Ihrss_slidespeed)) { $Ihrss_slidespeed = 1; }
    if(!is_numeric($Ihrss_slideshowgap)) { $Ihrss_slideshowgap = 5; }

    $Ihrss_slideshowgaphtml = "padding-right:".$Ihrss_slideshowgap."px;";

    $sSql = "select Ihrss_path,Ihrss_link,Ihrss_target,Ihrss_title from ".WP_Ihrss_TABLE." where 1=1";
    if($Ihrss_type <> ""){ $sSql = $sSql . " and Ihrss_type='".$Ihrss_type."'"; }
    if($Ihrss_random == "YES"){ $sSql = $sSql . " ORDER BY RAND()"; }else{ $sSql = $sSql . " ORDER BY Ihrss_order"; }

    $data = $wpdb->get_results($sSql);

    $cnt = 0;
    if ( ! empty($data) ) 
    {
        foreach ( $data as $data ) 
        {
            $Ihrss_path = trim($data->Ihrss_path);
            $Ihrss_link = trim($data->Ihrss_link);
            $Ihrss_target = trim($data->Ihrss_target);
            $Ihrss_title = trim($data->Ihrss_title);
            $Ihrss_package = $Ihrss_package ."IHRSS_SLIDESRARRAY[$cnt]='<li style=\"display:inline-block;\"><a style=\"$Ihrss_slideshowgaphtml\" title=\"$Ihrss_title\" target=\"$Ihrss_target\" href=\"$Ihrss_link\"><img alt=\"$Ihrss_title\" src=\"$Ihrss_path\" /></a></li>';   ";
            $cnt++;
        }

        $Ihrss_pluginurl = get_option('siteurl') . "/wp-content/plugins/image-horizontal-reel-scroll-slideshow/";

        $Ihrss = $Ihrss .'<script language="JavaScript1.2">';
        $Ihrss = $Ihrss .'var IHRSS_WIDTH = "'.$Ihrss_sliderwidth.'px"; ';
        $Ihrss = $Ihrss .'var IHRSS_HEIGHT = "'.$Ihrss_sliderheight.'px"; ';
        $Ihrss = $Ihrss .'var IHRSS_SPEED = '. $Ihrss_slidespeed.'; ';
        $Ihrss = $Ihrss .'var IHRSS_BGCOLOR = "'.$Ihrss_slidebgcolor.'"; ';
        $Ihrss = $Ihrss .'var IHRSS_SLIDESRARRAY=new Array(); ';
        $Ihrss = $Ihrss .'var IHRSS_FINALSLIDE =" "; ';
        $Ihrss = $Ihrss .$Ihrss_package;
        $Ihrss = $Ihrss .'var IHRSS_IMGGAP = " "; ';
        $Ihrss = $Ihrss .'var IHRSS_PIXELGAP = 1; ';
        $Ihrss = $Ihrss .'</script>';
        $Ihrss = $Ihrss .'<script language="JavaScript1.2" src="'.$Ihrss_pluginurl.'/image-horizontal-reel-scroll-slideshow.js"></script>';
    }   
    else
    {
        $Ihrss = $Ihrss . __('No images available in this Gallery Type. Please check admin setting.', 'ihrss');
    }
    return $Ihrss;
}

function Ihrss_add_to_menu() 
{
    if (is_admin()) 
    {
        add_options_page(__('Image horizontal reel scroll slideshow', 'ihrss'), 
                            __('Image horizontal reel scroll slideshow', 'ihrss'), 'manage_options', "image-horizontal-reel-scroll-slideshow", 'Ihrss_admin_options' );
    }
}

function Ihrss_init()
{
    if(function_exists('wp_register_sidebar_widget')) 
    {
        wp_register_sidebar_widget('Image-horizontal-reel-scroll-slideshow', __('Image horizontal reel scroll slideshow', 'ihrss'), 'Ihrss_widget');
    }

    if(function_exists('wp_register_widget_control')) 
    {
        wp_register_widget_control('Image-horizontal-reel-scroll-slideshow', array(__('Image horizontal reel scroll slideshow', 'ihrss'), 'widgets'), 'Ihrss_control');
    } 
}

function Ihrss_deactivation() 
{
    // No action required.
}

function Ihrss_textdomain() 
{
      load_plugin_textdomain( 'ihrss', false, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages/' );
}

add_action('plugins_loaded', 'Ihrss_textdomain');
add_action('admin_menu', 'Ihrss_add_to_menu');
add_action("plugins_loaded", "Ihrss_init");
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'Ihrss_install');
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'Ihrss_deactivation');
?>
```

i wrapped `a` tag with `li` tag at lines 67 and 219

I hope this will fix your issue. It worked well for me.

Comment: I tried this, gave the div a class and used this css: .ihrss-box img {
  display: inline;
}

Now the two div's #test2 and #test3 are on top of eachother, almost worked but not quite, any more advice?

Comment: @user123123, i made some changes at plugins core files an added the code in my answer. These files are main .js and .php files for plugin.

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much! :D You might want to edit your answer and take off the part about adding the class and css since it's not needed anymore.

Comment: @user123123, you are welcome, i'm glad that i could help :)

Answer (score 0):

I try to modify 
http://dev.lhpssa.org/wp-content/plugins/image-horizontal-reel-scroll-slideshow//image-horizontal-reel-scroll-slideshow.js

and combine with inline call

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            var IHRSS_WIDTH = "940px"; 
            var IHRSS_HEIGHT = "170px"; 
            var IHRSS_SPEED = 3; 
            var IHRSS_BGCOLOR = "#FFFFFF"; 
            var IHRSS_SLIDESRARRAY=new Array(); 
            var IHRSS_FINALSLIDE =" "; 
            IHRSS_SLIDESRARRAY[0]='<a style="float:left;padding-right:5px;width25px;" title="Antique Reels" target="_blank" href="http://www.antiquereels.com/tomgreene/index.html"><img alt="Antique Reels" src="http://dev.lhpssa.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/customrodandreel.jpg" /></a>';   
            IHRSS_SLIDESRARRAY[1]='<a style="float:left;padding-right:5px;width25px;" title="Holy Cross Ortho" target="_blank" href="http://www.holy-cross.com/orthopaedics/kleinhenz.php"><img alt="Holy Cross Ortho" src="http://dev.lhpssa.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/holycrosshospital.jpg" /></a>';    
            IHRSS_SLIDESRARRAY[2]='<a style="float:left;padding-right:5px;width25px;" title="Holy Cross Hospital" target="_blank" href="http://www.holy-cross.com/orthopaedics/kleinhenz.php"><img alt="Holy Cross Hospital" src="http://dev.lhpssa.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/tracysands.jpg" /></a>'; 
            IHRSS_SLIDESRARRAY[3]='<a style="float:left;padding-right:5px;width25px;" title="Re/Max" target="_blank" href="http://www.southfloridahouses.net"><img alt="Re/Max" src="http://dev.lhpssa.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Screen-Shot-2014-01-09-at-4.05.50-PM.png" /></a>';    
            var IHRSS_IMGGAP = " "; 
            var IHRSS_PIXELGAP = 1; 



            var copyspeed=IHRSS_SPEED
            IHRSS_SLIDESRARRAY=IHRSS_SLIDESRARRAY.join(IHRSS_IMGGAP)
            var iedom=document.all||document.getElementById
            if (iedom)
            document.write('<span id="temp" style="visibility:hidden;position:absolute;top:-100px;left:-9000px">'+IHRSS_SLIDESRARRAY+'</span>')
            var actualwidth=''
            var cross_slide, ns_slide

            function fillup(){
            if (iedom){
            cross_slide=document.getElementById? document.getElementById("test2") : document.all.test2
            cross_slide2=document.getElementById? document.getElementById("test3") : document.all.test3
            cross_slide.innerHTML=cross_slide2.innerHTML=IHRSS_SLIDESRARRAY
            actualwidth=document.all? cross_slide.offsetWidth : document.getElementById("temp").offsetWidth
            cross_slide2.style.left=actualwidth+IHRSS_PIXELGAP+"px"
            }
            else if (document.layers){
            ns_slide=document.ns_slidemenu.document.ns_slidemenu2
            ns_slide2=document.ns_slidemenu.document.ns_slidemenu3
            ns_slide.document.write(IHRSS_SLIDESRARRAY)
            ns_slide.document.close()
            actualwidth=ns_slide.document.width
            ns_slide2.left=actualwidth+IHRSS_PIXELGAP
            ns_slide2.document.write(IHRSS_SLIDESRARRAY)
            ns_slide2.document.close()
            }
            lefttime=setInterval("slideleft()",30)
            }
            window.onload=fillup

            function slideleft(){
            if (iedom){
            if (parseInt(cross_slide.style.left)>(actualwidth*(-1)+8))
            cross_slide.style.left=parseInt(cross_slide.style.left)-copyspeed+"px"
            else
            cross_slide.style.left=parseInt(cross_slide2.style.left)+actualwidth+IHRSS_PIXELGAP+"px"

            if (parseInt(cross_slide2.style.left)>(actualwidth*(-1)+8))
            cross_slide2.style.left=parseInt(cross_slide2.style.left)-copyspeed+"px"
            else
            cross_slide2.style.left=parseInt(cross_slide.style.left)+actualwidth+IHRSS_PIXELGAP+"px"

            }
            else if (document.layers){
            if (ns_slide.left>(actualwidth*(-1)+8))
            ns_slide.left-=copyspeed
            else
            ns_slide.left=ns_slide2.left+actualwidth+IHRSS_PIXELGAP

            if (ns_slide2.left>(actualwidth*(-1)+8))
            ns_slide2.left-=copyspeed
            else
            ns_slide2.left=ns_slide.left+actualwidth+IHRSS_PIXELGAP
            }
            }

            if (iedom||document.layers){
            with (document){
            document.write('<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><td>')
            if (iedom){
            write('<div style="position:relative;width:'+IHRSS_WIDTH+';height:'+IHRSS_HEIGHT+';overflow:hidden">')
            write('<div style="position:absolute;width:'+IHRSS_WIDTH+';height:'+IHRSS_HEIGHT+';background-color:'+IHRSS_BGCOLOR+'" onMouseover="copyspeed=0" onMouseout="copyspeed=IHRSS_SPEED">')
            write('<div id="test2" style="float:left;position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;width:1400px;"></div>')
            write('<div id="test3" style="float:left;position:absolute;left:-1000px;top:0px;width:1400px;"></div>')
            write('</div></div>')
            }
            else if (document.layers){
            write('<ilayer width='+IHRSS_WIDTH+' height='+IHRSS_HEIGHT+' name="ns_slidemenu" bgColor='+IHRSS_BGCOLOR+'>')
            write('<layer name="ns_slidemenu2" left=0 top=0 onMouseover="copyspeed=0" onMouseout="copyspeed=IHRSS_SPEED"></layer>')
            write('<layer name="ns_slidemenu3" left=0 top=0 onMouseover="copyspeed=0" onMouseout="copyspeed=IHRSS_SPEED"></layer>')
            write('</ilayer>')
            }
            document.write('</td></table>')
            }
            }
        </script>
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Changing the script this way would break the plugin. Users need to be able to add images in the back-end of wordpress. Could you please provide me with a version of the script that would still allow for that functionality to work? The plugin and that file can be found here:   https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/image-horizontal-reel-scroll-slideshow